# how to add old version of vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I put "vue add vuetify@1.5" in my Linux console error, vuetify is currently in version 2.0.2 if I put "vue add vuetify" by default the latest version is added I want an earlier version.

Comment: Don't add it via Vue-Cli 3 while creating your project. Add it to your project with: **npm install vuetify@version --save**

Answer (score 3):

Go to your package.json and change line with `"vuetify"` to `"vuetify": "1.5"`.

Then run `npm install`. Or `yarn install`, depending on what package manager you use.

Alternatively do `npm install vuetify@1.5 --save` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

or `yarn add vuetify@1.5` (https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/)