# how to install vuetify 1.5.18

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

how to install vuetify version 1.5.18? I followed this method https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify/issues/99, but in this way I got version 2.0.0. I followed this method [how to add old version of vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255773/how-to-add-old-version-of-vuetify) and adding this code into App.vue (this code vuetify version 1.5.18 toolbars):

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar>
    <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

did not happen, there was no vuetify only plain text. What should I do?

Comment: you can find any of the vuetify releases versions on this given link -> https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use following link to install your required version of vuetify,

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v1.5.18

Answer (score 1):

try `npm install vuetify@1.5.8`

or in package.json change version of vuetify to 1.5.8 then do `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Use: `npm i vuetify@1.5.*` or specify last point version, ex. `npm i vuetify@1.5.18`.